# If $BA = I_n$, then why can't we do $BAx = Bb$ to solve $Ax=b$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices such that $BA = I_n$. As an exercise I am to explain why the following argument is invalid:

To solve $A\vec x=\vec b$ with this initial condition, multiply both sides by $B$, and nothing that $BA = I_n$, we have $\vec x = B\vec b$

I don't see how there's anything wrong with this. $B$ clearly seems to be $A^{-1}$. I feel like the fault in my understanding why the above statement isn't necessarily true would be that $B$ isn't necessarily isn't $A^{-1}$, but I don't know how this is not the case given $BA = I_n$.

To those who don't see anything wrong with it, I'll take a picture of the 
problem for reference:

-
[image]

Comment: Who said it is invalid?

Comment: It looks good to me

Comment: I agree - but apparently it is, according to the exercise

Comment: Is this in a computational numerical analysis context?  If so, the answer might be that this method is more prone to numerical error than other methods.

Comment: You all appear to be assuming that $A$ is square. I don’t see that anywhere in the pasted-in problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a correct procedure if $A$ and $B$ are both square matrices. However, if the matrices are not square, $B \vec b$ is not necessarily a solution.

Take for example $A =\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$ with $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\vec b = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $BA = I_1$, but $B \vec b = 0$ is not a solution of the equation.

Comment: But it says $I$ is an $nxn$ matrix. So how could $A$ or $B$ not be square?

Comment: Just look at my example, A and B are both non square.

Comment: @sangstar The product of an $n\times m$ matrix with an $m\times n$ matrix is $n\times n$.

Comment: Ah, I see, and is $A^t$ transpose of $A$? What would that look like as a $1 \times 2$? matrix?

Comment: Yes, it is a 1 x 2 matrix.

Comment: What is $B$, in this case, explicitly? Ah, I've just noticed your edit.

Comment: Also, why is $B \vec b$ not a solution to the equation? What's wrong with $I_1 x = 0$?

Comment: The equation is $Ax = b$ and $0$ is simply no solution of this equation.

Comment: But why, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

This is a subtle but important point:

You're assuming that the vector $x$ exists when you do the above.  If you set $x = Bb$ and then check $A(Bb)$, this is only equal to $b$ if $AB = I$.  This doesn't need to be true!  For instance, take $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$, and try this with $b = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding your answer, but $BA \ne I$ in your example.

Comment: @sangstar, $BA = [1] = I_1$

Comment: Oh, right! I forgot just a $1$ can be an identity matrix.

Comment: @sangstar, Right.  The point is that this procedure only works when you also have $AB = I$; $BA = I \implies $AB = I$ if they're both square, but this example shows that it doesn't happen in general.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that $Ax = b$ might not have a solution.

It is correct to say that *if* $Ax = b$ then $x = Bb$.  However, if $b$ is not in the range of $A$, then $Bb$ is *not* a solution to $Ax = b$.